# Pressure distribution on an inclined plate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image: [Liquid exiting a nozzle and exerting a pressure force on an inclined plate ]]

Hi there, I'm attempting a fluid mechanics questions that requires me to sketch a pressure distribution along the surface of the plate and explain why it shaped the way it is. I'm struggling to comprehend how to sketch this distribution. Does it vary linearly/non-linearly? Is it continuous or constant along the plate? My general thoughts are that it would be it triangular shaped and would decrease linearly as you went further away from where the water jet strikes the plate.

If anybody could help me out with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: What is the pressure in the air immediately adjacent to the thin water layer on the plate?  Is pressure continuous at the interface between the water and the air?  Is the thickness of the water layer changing with spatial position on the slide?  Are you supposed to include viscous friction, or are you supposed to treat the water as inviscid.  If the angle $\theta$ were zero, what would be your assessment of how the thickness of the water layer varies with position?

Answer (score 1):

You could find the mass flow rate from the column of water and derive the force, then derive the components of that force in relation to the slope of the plane. There will be some additional forces from the water falling toward the column of water but I feel like they could be neglected because they would cancel out. I hope this gets you started on solving your problem.